# Using gatsby-remark-component with gatsby-remark-images

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to use `gatsby-remark-images` alongside `gatsby-remark-component`, to get a parsed image path within a custom component.

Both plugins work great on their own. I'm now trying to establish a custom component that has a particular layout for a custom and alignment:

*markdown*

`<img alt="Some alt text" src="foo.png" caption="Some caption" align="center"></img>`

And the component:

*JSX*

`<Container align={align}>
    <img src={src} alt={alt} title={caption} />
    {caption && (
      <Caption>{caption}</Caption>
    )}
  </Container>`

Unfortunately, it looks the `src` won't get caught by `gatsby-remark-images` when doing this.

Is there an alternative approach to dealing with this? It doesn't look like `gatsby-remark-images` provides enough granularity in regards to rendering details to negate the use of `gatsby-remark-component`, though I could be missing something.